# Orderby function with unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have setup a query to list my posts ordered by a certain custom field (which is the publish date of the individual books reviewed in my blog).

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'book',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'meta_key'          => 'book_release_date',
    'meta_type'         => 'NUMERIC',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

I have then called it this way:

```
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php if (is_category()) { ?>
<div class="page-title" align="center">
<h2 class="page-title-border">
<?php _e(' Books:'); ?> 
<?php echo single_cat_title(); ?> (<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>) 
</h2>
</div>
<?php } ?><?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```

There's a problem tho: homepage shows posts basing on last released book order, BUT each category, research etc now always shows as result, the last released books in general, without respecting the category requested nor the keyword used for the research.

Why is this happening?

The weird part is if I add `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` just after the latest row above, it will correctly show a correct result, but first result is displayed 10x times, always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your custom `WP_Query` with the following:

```
set_query_var( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
set_query_var( 'orderby', 'DESC' );
set_query_var( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' );
set_query_var( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );
```

It sounds like you had a working list of *Books* that filtered by *Category*, etc., and now you are trying to tap into that list to add the `orderby`. If so then I see one problem: Your posted code would lose the filtering because you've created an entirely new [post loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#multiple-loops). The fact that [wp_reset_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) restores the filtered posts-loop leads me to believe that we can simply amend this existing query via [set_query_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_query_var/) versus create a new `WP_Query`.

BONUS: If you are using `pre_get_posts` in your `functions.php` then do the following:

```
function wpse139657_orderby($query){ 
    // Uncomment this if() statement once you confirm that the orderby works
    //if (is_admin() || $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'book') return $query;

    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );

    return $query;
} 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');
```

Comment: You have understood correctly. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. By the way your code is not working, unfortunately. First of all the ';' is not accepted in functions.php file. I have edited it into ',' but still it doesn't work.

Comment: huh. I don't know why you would have to change semicolons to commas. When you say "it doesnt work", are you saying that it throws an error? Or are you saying that it doesn't appear to have any effect?

Comment: Assuming I have to still work with this, still in functions.php file, like the one above I posted, if I replace my code with $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
followed by your set query vars, it doesn't allow me to save, saying those ';' arent expected. If I replace em with comma, it allows me to save but the website doesn't load due to errors. If I introduce your set query vars with function set_query_var( $var, $value ) { it still doesn't let me save due to errors. Sorry maybe I'm just too newbie for this and you are assuming I have some basic knowledge that I actually haven't :"D

Comment: Also tried the following, without working (it doesn't appear to have any effect): function wpse139657_orderby(){  
set_query_var( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
set_query_var( 'orderby', 'DESC' );
set_query_var( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' );
set_query_var( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');

Comment: Okay, I've added an alternative solution to my answer based on your last comment.

Comment: Im also double-checking whether the syntax is right for the orderby...

Comment: Tried. Still no apparent effect. Maybe I should replace current <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> and <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> with something else?

Comment: Well, I had a typo in the last solution, so please try it again (you should see the BONUS solution is slightly modified)

Comment: Bingo! It works just perfectly now! Thank you so much for your kind efforts and time!

Comment: Excellent! See my last edit on the BONUS solution. You will need to add an if-statement (like the one I've shown above) to protect your other queries on your site.

Comment: You're right, the code is actually unactivating other functions in function.php file. I tried to add if (is_admin() || $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'book') return $query;
as you suggested, but this stops your code to be still working. Now it's not showing the book release order any longer :(

Comment: You will have to modify the if-statement so it lets your Book query through, but nothing else. Unfortunately, how to do this depends on too many factors for me to give you a quick snippet. Take a step back and look at what we've been able to do and hopefully you can start working on the solution yourself.

Comment: It's okay. You did great. Thanks again man. Have a great day!

Comment: Would you ever help me again on this? I have posted several questions in the last 2 weeks to try and solve this, but none has been as competent as you on this matter :"D ... and I alone, I haven't been able to solve the issue. The code you provided me keeps working but invalidating some other queries in single posts. Last move I tried is this, to try and make it work on index page only but still, no success

Comment: function wpse139657_orderby($query){
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'book_release_date' ); 
    $query->set( 'meta_type', 'NUMERIC' );

        return $query;    } 
} 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');